# Range of variables or sth else? very beginning JS

Tags: javascript, button, input, global-variables, setattribute

Sorry for mistakes - my first post. I'd like to click on the 'Try it' button and change the type of the first 'ok' input. After this change I'd like to click the 'Try it' button again and change the type of the element with id="inputt" to INPUT again. I think it's sth wrong with the range of my variable done which tells if i have 2 buttons or input and button.

```
//JS
window.onload = function Load(){
var done = false;
var foo = document.getElementById('g');
 if(!done){
foo.onclick = Change1;
 }else{
foo.onclick = Change2;
}

};

function Change1(){
 inp = document.getElementById('inputt');
 inp.setAttribute('type', 'button');
 done = true;

}
function Change2(){
 but = document.getElementById('inputt');
 but.setAttribute('type','input');
}

//HTML
<input value="ok" id="inputt">
<p>Click the button below to set the type attribute of the button above.</p>
<button id="g">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Why do you expect your code to change it a second time?

Comment: there is 'var done = false' on the beginning, so i'm calling out Change1 and in this(Change1) i'm changing done to true. but my code seems to be a bit complicated

Comment: It'd be useful if you made a JSFiddle for us to test this. [JSFiddle](jsfiddle.net}

Comment: It doesn't work on fiddle (in my browser it's ok) http://jsfiddle.net/Akgzy/

Comment: By _range_ do you mean _scope_?

Comment: No, I thought about using for example 'var cat' and only 'cat' in functions and before them - how does it change its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.onload` event is not going to get executed again, it only happens once when the window...loads

see if this is what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/7W4Xw/1/

```
 //JS
 window.onload = function Load(){
     var foo = document.getElementById('g');
     foo.onclick = Change1;
 };

 function Change1(){
     inp = document.getElementById('inputt');
     inp.setAttribute('type', 'button');
     var foo = document.getElementById('g');
     foo.onclick = Change2;
 }

 function Change2(){
     but = document.getElementById('inputt');
     but.setAttribute('type','input');
 }
```

Comment: Please include the solution in the answer itself, and explain it.

Comment: Can I just skip the window.onload in documents? If i'll do it code is not working

Comment: Sure, you could assign the function Change1 to the `onclick` event in the markup:
<input type='button' ... onclick='javascript:Change1();'>

there is no reason to have to use the `onload` event.